# How to layout partial overlay ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem to implement this situation, Seen here that natively has let the entire layout as belowlayout below.
[image]

But I would like to do this, this rectangle Should be a single and clickable item [image]

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a custom theme that extends an existing action bar theme and set the android:windowActionBarOverlay property to true.

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And add the following in your layout:

```
android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

Example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"> // <==== add this one
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Read more about [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html).

Comment: in this case the ActionBar overlap RelativeLayout. the layout down  the ActionBar it can be clicked , clicking over the ActionBar ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display something over the main content a[PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) will be the best choice.

Comment: Yes, but in this case I need this item is part of the layout of the activity, and not a popup.

Comment: Why? It's not just popup, you can configure it's behaviour, for example, it can be touchable outseide the view and interept clicks if you click on it. By the way, you don't have many options to accomplish such behaviour.